# How to use special unicode characters in string in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display this text `word1 • word2 • word3` and I found that in [this flutter doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/charcode.htmlentity.dollar_lowercase/$middot-constant.html) there  is a `$middot` constant but I cant find it inside the `ascii.dart` file .
I also tried to define a `const int $middot = 0x00B7;` and use it in my text like `word1 ${$middot} word2 ${$middot} word3`, but the middot is simple ignored and I get `word1 word2 word3`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can the person downvoting please explain as to why the downvote and what could be improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use this and it works:

```
const kInterPunctChr = '\u22C5';

final words = 'word1 $kInterPunctChr word2';
```

Comment: But I think you made a typo. It should be `$kInterPunctChr`

Answer (score 2):

```
Text(String.fromCharCode(9792););
```

You can find most of Unicode string over here [unicodes](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9792&number=128&names=2)